# Ubuntu 20.04 reads incorrect battery level to critical which causes laptop to shutdown

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, battery, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P2 running Ubuntu 20.04. I am getting critically low battery level even though I have more than 80% charge at times. Due to this, my laptop shuts down within a minute or two losing all my work.

But "sometimes", when I open the "Power Settings" in Gnome during this period, the battery percentage returns to normal level. But this doesn't always happen. I have also set critical battery level action to "nothing" from dconf-editor. But still the laptop shuts down.

I have tried calibrating the battery using Thinkpad's utilities. The battery life seems to be fine. I have tried running the "power-calibrate" tool as one of the forums suggested. I have tried charging my battery to full and running out the battery completely before charging it again. But nothing seem to help.

I used to run Ubuntu 18.04 prior to this which did not have this issue. This seems to be happening after I upgraded to 20.04.

These are the logs I find in "journalctl -r" when the shutdown happens

```
May 20 10:25:22 nitin systemd-logind[1243]: System is powering down.
May 20 10:25:22 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:22 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:12 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:12 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:10 nitin systemd[2412]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:25:08 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:25:07 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:07 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:25:07 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:25:02 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:02 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:02 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:02 nitin kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
May 20 10:25:01 nitin CRON[9033]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 20 10:25:01 nitin CRON[9034]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 20 10:25:01 nitin CRON[9033]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 20 10:23:49 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:23:49 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:23:49 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 20 10:23:49 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 20 10:23:49 nitin gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
```

None of the solutions from this forum seem to help. Any help greatly appreciated!

~

EDIT 1:

Something I noticed recently, when the critical battery notification pops, I go ahead and lock my screen. Then after a few seconds when I unlock my screen the battery level returns to the actual percentage. This kind of helps me work around the problem of not losing my work at least.

I feel like it is gnome-shell that is somehow reporting incorrect battery readings. Then when I lock and unlock screen, gnome-shell somehow reloads the correct battery state.

EDIT 2:

I am actually seeing "upower" returning incorrect battery capacity. As you can notice from the "updated" timestamps, the battery percentage is down to 3%. Then after I lock-unlock my screen the battery percentage returns to its original percentage.

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Celxpert
  model:                5B10V98091
  serial:               4143
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 08 Jul 2022 05:02:54 AM PDT (19 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       critical
    energy:              2.31 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         145.98 Wh
    energy-full-design:  80.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         13.419 W
    voltage:             15.714 V
    time to empty:       10.3 minutes
    percentage:          3%
    capacity:            91.99%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1657281774  3.000   discharging
  History (rate):
    1657281774  13.419  discharging

# After locking and unlocking the screen 
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Celxpert
  model:                5B10V98091
  serial:               4143
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 08 Jul 2022 05:03:24 AM PDT (18 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              53.38 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         145.98 Wh
    energy-full-design:  80.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         13.75 W
    voltage:             15.312 V
    time to empty:       3.9 hours
    percentage:          71%
    capacity:            91.99%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1657281804  71.000  discharging
    1657281774  3.000   discharging
  History (rate):
    1657281804  13.750  discharging
    1657281774  13.419  discharging
```

Comment: Having the exact same issue with a Thinkpad X1 extreme, also after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. You didn't end up finding any solution here, did you?